# pandas DataFrame "no numeric data to plot" error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a small DataFrame that I want to plot using pandas.

```
    2   3
0   1300    1000
1   242751149   199446827
2   237712649   194704827
3   16.2    23.0
```

I am still trying to learn plotting from within pandas . I want a plot In the above example when I say .

```
df.plot()
```

I get the strangest error.

```
Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/pandas/tools/plotting.pyc in _compute_plot_data(self)
   1015         if is_empty:
   1016             raise TypeError('Empty {0!r}: no numeric data to '
-> 1017                             'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
   1018 
   1019         self.data = numeric_data

TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

While I understand that the DataFrame with its very lopsided values makes a very un-interesting plot. I am wondering why the error message complains of no numeric data to plot.

Comment: What data types do you see if you run `df.dtypes`?

Comment: Your DataFrame probably contains numeric strings. It doesn't look like the columns were correctly parsed -- you might have just one column called `'2     3'`.
To help you fix this we'd probably need to see how `df` was defined.

Comment: Also, looks like you may have row-oriented data and pandas is going to expect column-oriented, you might want to transpose.

Comment: df.info() will give you the columns and data types of each column.

Answer (score 119):

Try the following before plotting:

```
df=df.astype(float)
```

There's a lot of magic behind pandas, for instance, when you use `pandas.read_csv` to read a file. In particular, it has to infer the data type. Sometimes it gets it wrong. The code above forces pandas to try and convert the data to floating point numbers.

Comment: I wish an explanation was provided for solutions like these. If someone comes about my comment and understands this answer fully, please provide an explanation.

Comment: @GregHilston there's a lot of magic behind pandas for instance when you use pandas.read_csv to read a file. In particular it has to infer the data type. Sometimes it gets it wrong. My answer above forces pandas to try and convert the data to floating point numbers.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Hey there! Yea, this does seem very straight forward to me now. At the time, I was brand new to Pandas and did not understand what was happening at all. I'm with you now, but people who are new might be in the same boat I once was. Happy coding!

Comment: my data inside the df are strings. I just want a table. I also get this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

To solve this you have to convert the particular column or columns you want to 
    use to numeric. First let me create a simple dataframe with `pandas` and `numpy` to 
    understand it better.

```
#creating the dataframe

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
details=[['kofi',30,'male',1.5],['ama',43,'female',2.5]]
pf=pd.DataFrame(np.array(details),[0,1],['name','age','sex','id'])

pf  #here i am calling the dataframe

   name age     sex   id
0  kofi  30    male  1.5
1   ama  43  female  2.5

#to make your plot work you need to convert the columns that have numbers into numeric
as seen below 

pf.id=pd.to_numeric(pf.id)
pf.age=pd.to_numeric(pf.age)

pf.plot.scatter(x='id',y='age')

#This should work perfectly
```

Comment: Regarding `pf.id=pd.to_numeric(pf.id)`, how do you do this if the column header has more than one word in it? For example, I have a column named 'Percent Working'.

Comment: @KesPerron try this: pf['Percent Working']

Comment: my data inside the df are strings. I just want a table. I also get this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by alex314159, if you have other data than float in the same table

```
df["YourColumnNameHere"]=df["YourColumnNameHere"].astype(float)
```

Comment: my data inside the df are strings. I just want a table. I also get this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Convert non numeric data into numeric using:

```
DataFrame["Column_name"] = DataFrame["Column_name"].str.replace("[\$\,\.]", "")
```