# pandas dataframe: convert symbol -

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am working with pandas DataFrame. If I print the dataframe, it contains some columns with scripts(-) in place of numbers. When I use the data to make charts, termninal returns:

```
TypeError: Empty 'Series': no numeric data to plot
```

Can those script (-) data points not to be used when making the graph? Do they need to be replaced? If it is so, how?

The code I wrote is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('data', sep=',')
a_list=list(df.columns.values)
#df=df.astype(float)
for ielement in range(len(a_list)):
    print ("column name is %s" %(a_list[ielement]))
    if a_list[ielement]!= 'age':
        df.plot(x='age', y=a_list[ielement])
        plt.savefig(a_list[ielement] + '.png')
        plt.clf()
```

**Examle Data**

`data.csv`

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,nn,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,hh
    12,2798,3.9,3.0,1.1,4.0,0.1,5.0,0.0,-,0.1,35.5,0.2,52.0,1.6,19.0,2.0,36.0,0.1,24.5,0.2,52.0,0.2,2.0,0.0,-,0.2,13.0
    13,2757,8.5,6.0,3.4,15.0,0.1,1.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,-,0.6,6.0,2.5,12.0,2.4,14.0,0.1,41.0,0.3,25.5,0.3,4.0,0.1,5.0,0.1,19.0
    14,2792,18.1,5.0,8.7,24.0,0.1,5.5,0.0,-,0.1,2.0,1.6,3.0,2.6,5.0,3.9,12.0,0.4,4.5,0.9,5.0,0.8,12.0,0.1,24.0,0.2,16.5
    15,2956,29.2,6.0,14.5,25.0,0.5,4.0,0.1,9.5,0.2,1.0,2.1,4.0,2.5,5.5,5.5,10.0,0.8,3.0,2.0,4.5,1.5,6.0,0.3,10.5,0.4,30.0
```

Using Evan's answer: `df.replace(to_replace = '-', value = np.nan, inplace = True)`still got same error.

and it works for the first columns, because these don't have scripts(-)

Comment: Can you give an sample of the dataframe values as well as the code you used to make the plots because a `-` symbol is not numeric, which conflicts with your statement that all values are numbers?

Comment: Could you run the following command after loading your df and see if you see any columns that have an object datatype: `df.dtypes`? If there are, then those are your faulty columns, which means that pandas has treated that entire column as a non-numeric dtype column.

Comment: there are some object columns..what can I do?@Scratch'N'Purr

Answer (score 1):

Ok, given your comments, you have 2 options:

1. Where there is the `-` symbol for the column(s), you remove the entire row.
2. Where there is the `-` symbol for the column(s), you set a default value for it.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [11, 22, '-', 44], 'col3': ['-', 3, 5, 7]})
>>> df.dtypes
col1     int64
col2    object
col3    object
dtype: object
>>> df
   col1 col2 col3
0     1   11    -
1     2   22    3
2     3    -    5
3     4   44    7
```

*Option 1*

```
>>> for col in df.columns:
...     if df[col].dtype == 'object':
...         df = df[df[col] != '-']
... 
>>> df
   col1 col2 col3
1     2   22    3
3     4   44    7
```

*Option 2*

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> for col in df.columns:
...     if df[col].dtype == 'object':
...         df[col] = np.where(df[col] == '-', 0, df[col])  # set `-` symbol values to 0
...         df[col] = df[col].astype(float)  # cast column to float
... 
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1  11.0   0.0
1     2  22.0   3.0
2     3   0.0   5.0
3     4  44.0   7.0
```

Comment: Thanks. But can't it be replaced by a value which then is not plotted? There must be many data frames with the same issue of missing data..

Comment: If you want to not plot it, wouldn't that be the same as deleting the row before plotting? Also, you can check out `pandas.DataFrame.replace` or `pandas.DataFrame.fillna`.

Comment: @Evan but I need to replace for a special value? I don't want zero, because it will be a false data-point

Comment: @Evan If It is replaced by Nan, then columns are still objects so it is not useful.

Comment: @santimirandarp Unfortunately, you can't really have the best of both worlds. If you want to plot only the "true" values (values that don't have the special characters), then you have to remove the records from the dataframe from plotting. You could however create a separate dataframe that has only the rows with the special characters to still preserve those records for later analysis. Also, if you don't want to set those values to 0, you can change it to whatever other value you want. I just set it to 0 as an example. Also @Evan made a good point about the `replace` and `fillna` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing @Scratch'N'Purr's code, here's my solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [11, 22, '-', 44], 'col3': ['-', 3, 5, 7]})
```

df:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0   1   11  -
1   2   22  3
2   3   -   5
3   4   44  7

df.replace(to_replace = '-', value = np.nan, inplace = True)
df = df.astype(float) # added after OP feedback
```

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3
0   1   11.0    NaN
1   2   22.0    3.0
2   3   NaN     5.0
3   4   44.0    7.0
```

Plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: df plot]

I did not look at the data closely; does this solution plot the way you'd hoped? Second, going from `int` to `float` is computationally expensive, but works well enough for small enough data sets.

Edit: See [pandas DataFrame "no numeric data to plot" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494870/pandas-dataframe-no-numeric-data-to-plot-error)

In order to plot `NaN`'s, convert to `float`. The above (edited) code generated PNG images a through hh, based on OP's updated post.

Comment: If you don't set `inplace = True`, pandas will return (in Jupyter or whatever) an updated `df`, but won't change the value of `df` that is stored in memory. You can use `df = df.modify(args)`, but I just use `inplace = True` because it makes my code more readable (to me).

Comment: I can't get why but althought values are replaced those columns still can't be plotted & get the same error because NaN values are recognized as objects

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Is there an entire column of '-' values?

Comment: Updated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494870/pandas-dataframe-no-numeric-data-to-plot-error  Unrelated, why doesn't `inplace = True` work for `df.astype()`?