# TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot, not sure what's wrong in my code?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to plot my model results from ARIMA but I keep receiving `TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame'`: no numeric data to plot
and I'm not sure why...

```
pred_ci = pred.conf_int()
ax = y['2016':].plot(label='observed')
pred.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='One-step ahead Forecast', alpha=.7, figsize=(14, 7))
ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.2)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Days Down')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

outputs the error:

`TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot`

Comment: Hard to tell based on the code shared here. Please provide a [mcve]. [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409415/process-list-of-dataframes-row-by-row-in-pyspark).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas DataFrame "no numeric data to plot" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494870/pandas-dataframe-no-numeric-data-to-plot-error)