# Creating DataFrame with Pandas from .txt File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble turning a .txt file into a dataframe of float values with pandas. I need to create a scatter plot of two columns of the data, but I keep getting the error "TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot" so I figure it's reading the data as strings.

The file I´m reading is 9,000 rows. I skip a few rows at the beginning as they are just text. When I run just the first line of my code, it seems to create a legitimate data frame, but then trying to make a scatter plot doesn´t end up working. The names of the columns come just before the data values in the file. The two I'm trying to make a scatter plot for are 'Xpos' vs 'Ypos'.

My code is really simple:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='|', skiprows=44)
df.plot(x='Xpos', y='Ypos')
```

Here is a sample of the first 20 lines of the dataframe

`Note   HHVA    Xpos    Ypos   ...       B-V  u_B-V  e_Vmag   e_B-V
2        10001   47.22   68.87   ...     0.731         0.010   0.010
3        10002   62.38   38.89   ...     0.921         0.010   0.010
4        10003  207.27  371.05   ...     0.884         0.010   0.010
5        10004  146.39  208.01   ...     0.791         0.010   0.010
6        10005  189.39  294.75   ...     1.392         0.011   0.016
7     *  10006  205.68  475.89   ...     0.645         0.013   0.015
8     *  10007  273.94  244.41   ...     0.546         0.004   0.009
9     *  10008  159.47  126.65   ...     0.593         0.009   0.012
10    *  10009   99.21  294.68   ...     0.622         0.010   0.012
11    *  10010  215.65   20.32   ...     0.558         0.005   0.009
12    *  10011   96.96  473.71   ...     0.582         0.009   0.011
13       10012  126.02  401.93   ...     1.174         0.010   0.013
14    *  10013  109.47  262.02   ...     0.557         0.010   0.013
15    *  10014   92.94  444.24   ...     0.569         0.008   0.012
16       10015  174.44  469.01   ...     0.554         0.012   0.015
17    *  10016   17.07  427.70   ...     0.549         0.013   0.016
18       10017  232.49  385.61   ...     0.781         0.007   0.011
19       10018  241.99  189.83   ...     0.511         0.024   0.029
20    *  10019  262.88  360.47   ...     0.544         0.004   0.008
21    *  10020  110.98  142.96   ...     0.535         0.011   0.014`

And here is what I get when I run df.info

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 20 entries, 2 to 21
Data columns (total 10 columns):
Note      20 non-null object
HHVA      20 non-null object
Xpos      20 non-null object
Ypos      20 non-null object
Vmag      20 non-null object
u_Vmag    20 non-null object
B-V       20 non-null object
u_B-V     20 non-null object
e_Vmag    20 non-null object
e_B-V     20 non-null object
dtypes: object(10)
memory usage: 1.7+ KB
None`

The columns u_Vmag and u_B-V do not have any measured values in them.

I feel like I´m just missing something glaringly obvious. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: what's *in* your dataframe, for starters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494870/pandas-dataframe-no-numeric-data-to-plot-error

Comment: It's a photometry data set of a star cluster. The columns are supposed to be ID (5 digit number), x position (in pixels), y position (in pixels), V band magnitude, B band magnitude, color (B-V magnitude), standard deviation of V band, and standard deviation of B-V.

Comment: the columns are supposed to be... well, are they? IOW, are you sure that your dataframe contains what you think it contains? If so, have you tried explictly casting them to float? What does `df.info` tell you? etc. Like, help us help you!

Comment: ok, I added some more info about the dataframe. When I try to do `df.astype(float)` I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`.

Comment: Best guess is there is some type of value in those columns, such as "2,300" that panda's doesn't like to convert.  Or maybe how missing values are set in the dataset?

Comment: I'm not familiar with matplotlib, so I'm not sure what's going on under the hood here but maybe try isolating the columns you need for the plot. Perhaps creating another frame of just the two columns you need, e.g., `plot_frame = frame.loc[:, ['Xpos','Ypos']]`. This will at least help rule out if the problem is in another column(s).

Answer (score 0):

Have `pandas.read_csv()` do the conversion of the input data as a function of the input data.  `read_csv()` is failing to detect the input type because of non-numeric data and upcasts to Object.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO
print(pd.__version__)

data = """
Note|HHVA|Xpos|Ypos|B-V|e_Vmag|e_B-V
1|10001|71.20|68.87|0.731|0.010|0.010
2|10001| |68.87|0.731|0.010|0.010
"""

def myconverter(x):
    try:
        f = float(x)
    except ValueError as ve:
        return np.nan
    return f

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), converters={'Xpos':myconverter}, sep='|', skiprows=0)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Produces

```
0.24.2
Note        int64
HHVA        int64
Xpos      float64
Ypos      float64
B-V       float64
e_Vmag    float64
e_B-V     float64
```